# Can't import existing keystore to Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, keytool

I am having trouble importing an existing keystore to Visual Studio 2017 (15.7.2) in order to sign my Xamarin.Android application.

I switched machines, so I had to do a fresh VS installation. I have successfully created an archive, but I can't get my old keystore imported into VS. No matter what I try, I get the same cryptic [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTg9U.png). I can sign the APK manually with the keytool, so it's not about a wrong password.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From this path in your old machine Copy the folder **Keystore** in the same path in your new machine:
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Xamarin\Mono for Android

Comment: I copied the key folder from this location to the exact same location in the new machine, restarted Visual Studio and the key was visible.

Still, this does not explain why I can't successfully import the actual  keystore that contained the original key to VS on the new machine.

Comment: Yes, and now you can easily sign your app with this key which is exactly the same key on original machine.

Comment: I tried to upload the APK to Play Console, and received an error that the upload cert was incorrect. I manually signed the APK with the apksigner tool, and the APK was correctly signed. Your suggestion didn't quite work as intended, as I can't sign the APK straight from Visual Studio.

Comment: Your two solutions must be exactly same on both machines which it makes sure that essential app information such as package name among others in AndroisManifest is exactly the same.

Comment: I use Git, so the solutions are identical. I tried to import the keystore from the location you suggested, but Visual Studio still incorrectly signs the APK. When I do it myself manually with the keystore from the location you suggested, the APK is signed with the right fingerprint, and is accepted by Play Console.

Comment: Install both apps(signed with two mentioned keys) on a device, check to see that does second app updates the first one or there would be two identical apps installed alongside each other?

Comment: you need to restart visual studio even if you had an error, error will disappear after raster the visual studio and key store will be visible