Issue Importing Existing Key from Visual Studio 2022 (v17.9.5) for Signing Android Application
I am trying to distribute an APK of my application created for Android (already uploaded to Play Store), and I am doing it from a different computer than the one I used for the first time. However, I am not able to do it from my new computer. I have been able to generate the APK correctly, I have used the same alias and the same password, but I have not found a way to solve this issue. Can anyone help me or knows how to resolve this situation?
I have tried without success: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57653728/error-importing-existing-keystore-in-vs2019-archive-manager-for-android[![enter image description here]1]1

The alias and the password are just to be able to access the key stored in a keystore file. Creating a new keystore with the same alias and password won't help you, you need to copy the keystore file from your old computer.

Finally, what has worked for me is: from this path on your old machine, copy the Keystore folder to the same path on your new machine: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Xamarin\Mono for Android
Can't import existing keystore to Visual Studio 2017
